# Tracking data changes in Vue.js on a Javascript that already exists?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I have a project that I've been working on for awhile that I might want to use vuejs for some of the UI elements. I fired up a tutorial and tried to piece together a basic example.

I have a basic javascript object like so:

```
var hex = {};
hex.turn_phase = 'unit_placement';
```

On my template, I have:

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#vue-test',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue!',
            turn_phase: hex.turn_phase,
        },
        delimiters: ["<%","%>"],
        mounted: function() {
            this.fetch_turn_phase();
        },
        methods: {
            fetch_turn_phase: function() {
                Vue.set(this, 'turn_phase', hex.turn_phase);
            },
        }
    });
```

This renders the correct turn_phase on the template initially, but if I change the hex.turn_phase in the browser console, the template doesn't react.

Is there something that I missed in this basic example?

Answer (score 0):

Vue creates all the [data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) variables, [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#ad) properties and values returned from [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#ad) reactive. in your case since you
are changing `hex`, which is not a vue variable, so vue will not detect any changes in this variable. However if you change `message` variable, it will be reflective and will be changed in the template.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have made things unnecessarily difficult. Just access your Vue instance via `app`?

Always make sure you go through the setters generated by Vue.js. These are watched and will re-render your component.

[image]

Instead, try using

```
app.turn_phase = 'unit_placement';
```

You can get a better understanding here, [Reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)